# Copy RootNode to ChildNode in JSON

Tags: c#, json, firebase-realtime-database

I got the below response from firebase. I need to copy the auto-generated root node as a child node.

```
{
"-LcjpjUB1ucnzDabnHa9": {
    "CustomerId": "9ff2a33e-815e-4d24-9985-2905c3460d8d",
    "DateTime": "4/18/2019 3:16:11 PM",
    "Id": "b59692a0-7fde-4132-aad7-d18a1aad690d",
    "OrderId": 11
},
"-Lcjs_DeDR8Q7kbuAdLo": {
    "CustomerId": "9ff2a33e-815e-4d24-9985-2905c3460d8d",
    "DateTime": "4/18/2019 3:28:33 PM",
    "Id": "be676d81-fa3f-4caa-8ea3-b921a705a09a",
    "OrderId": 12
}
}
```

Expected output

```
{
"-LcjpjUB1ucnzDabnHa9": {
    "AutoId":"-LcjpjUB1ucnzDabnHa9",
    "CustomerId": "9ff2a33e-815e-4d24-9985-2905c3460d8d",
    "DateTime": "4/18/2019 3:16:11 PM",
    "Id": "b59692a0-7fde-4132-aad7-d18a1aad690d",
    "OrderId": 11
},
"-Lcjs_DeDR8Q7kbuAdLo": {
    "AutoId":"-Lcjs_DeDR8Q7kbuAdLo",
    "CustomerId": "9ff2a33e-815e-4d24-9985-2905c3460d8d",
    "DateTime": "4/18/2019 3:28:33 PM",
    "Id": "be676d81-fa3f-4caa-8ea3-b921a705a09a",
    "OrderId": 12
}
}
```

I converted FireBaseResponse string to the above model using
`JObject json = JObject.Parse(firebaseResponse.Body);`

How can I achieve this?

Comment: Show some code that you did to achieve this? and also which library are you using for json manipulation either `newtonsoft` or `jil` or `javascript serializer` or any alse?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `Add` method of JObject. Iterate through json properties and add a new one in each node:

```
var input = "{\r\n\"-LcjpjUB1ucnzDabnHa9\": {\r\n    \"CustomerId\": \"9ff2a33e-815e-4d24-9985-2905c3460d8d\",\r\n    \"DateTime\": \"4/18/2019 3:16:11 PM\",\r\n    \"Id\": \"b59692a0-7fde-4132-aad7-d18a1aad690d\",\r\n    \"OrderId\": 11\r\n},\r\n\"-Lcjs_DeDR8Q7kbuAdLo\": {\r\n    \"CustomerId\": \"9ff2a33e-815e-4d24-9985-2905c3460d8d\",\r\n    \"DateTime\": \"4/18/2019 3:28:33 PM\",\r\n    \"Id\": \"be676d81-fa3f-4caa-8ea3-b921a705a09a\",\r\n    \"OrderId\": 12\r\n}\r\n}";

var json = JObject.Parse(input);
foreach (var token in json)
{
    var jObject = (JObject) token.Value;
    jObject.Add("AutoId", new JValue(token.Key));
}

var result = json.ToString(Formatting.Indented);
```

Answer (score 1):

1) Just loop through all properties of `JObject` that you parsed.

2) Add new property as `AutoID` with value as parent name to child objects.

3) And then assign this child object as it is to parent object in `JObject`.

```
JObject jObject = JObject.Parse(firebaseResponse.Body);

foreach (var prop in jObject.Properties())
{
    jObject[prop.Name] = JObject.FromObject(new
    {
        AutoId = prop.Name,                       //<= Child object name here
        CustomerId = prop.Value["CustomerId"],    //<= Remaining properties as it is
        DateTime = prop.Value["DateTime"],
        Id = prop.Value["Id"],
        OrderId = prop.Value["OrderId"]
    });
}

string outputJson = jObject.ToString();
```

**Output:** (From Debugger)

[image]